# NTUSER.dat - No of 100 ns intervals since 1.1.1601 UTC+0 using PHP

Tags: php

I am parsing UserAssist files from Windows registry NTUSER.dat. From the registry I get a field named "Last Executed" which has the explanation "Number of 100 ns intervals since 1.1.1601 UTC+0".
My decimal number is 131955686641390000, and I have to make this to a human readable format. I want to do this by using PHP.

I have figured out that there is a function called `add(new DateInterval('XXXX'));` that I think I can use, but I need some help to figure out what should be the input to the function. The manual is here; https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php

This is my code:

```
$nanoseconds = "131955686641390000";
$date = new DateTime('1601-01-01');
for($i=0;$i<100;$i++) {
    $date->add(new DateInterval('P1s'));                
}

$date_print = $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
echo"
<p><b>Date:</b> $date_print</p>
";
```

I tried this but it failed:

```
$nanoseconds = "131955686641390000";
$seconds = $nanoseconds/1000000000;
$add = "PT" . $seconds . "S";
$date = new DateTime('1601-01-01');
for($i=0;$i<100;$i++) {
    $date->add(new DateInterval($add));
}

$date_print = $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
echo"
<p><b>Date:</b> $date_print</p>
";
```

> Fatal error: Uncaught Exception: DateInterval::__construct(): Unknown
> or bad format (PT131955686.64139S) in
> C:\Users\user\wamp64\www\x.php:257
> DateInterval->__construct('PT131955686.641...') #1 {main} thrown in

Comment: is your platform 64 bit? because that number is too big for 32-bit system

Comment: Yes, I run Windows 10 64-bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unix epoch time is the number of seconds since Jan 1st, 1970. It consists of ten digits.

Your number is in hundreds of nano seconds, so that would work out as 11 digits.

So you can strip off everything after the first 11 digits, and pass that into a `DateTime` starting in 1601, like so:

```
<?php

$nano = '131955686641390000';
$seconds = substr($nano, 0, 11);
$date = new DateTime('1601-01-01');
$date->modify('+' . $seconds . ' seconds');

echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Which gives `2019-02-25 11:44:24`.

You can see this here https://3v4l.org/fYpSJ

Alternatively, you can subtract the number of seconds being the difference from Jan 1st 1970, to get the same result.

```
<?php

$nano = '131955686641390000';
$seconds = ((int) substr($nano, 0, 11)) -11644474772;
$date = new DateTime('@' . $seconds);

echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

That's a little shorter and cleaner in my opinion. Looks like `-11644474772` is a useful number to remember!

Comment: This is Microsoft time, so it starts at 1601-01-01. The answer should be something in 2019.

Comment: I just noticed that? Microsoft Time? The year 1601?!?!? Is that right? :-P If you give the exact start date we should be able to figure this out

Comment: The exact start date is January 1st 1601. Then I need to add 100 ns intervalls, thats why I have the loop 100 times..

Comment: got it! Updating answer